# Creating a button with a dynamic link to a page based on data in Wordpress User Object

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to add a 'Book Now' button on my home page that takes logged in users to a specific page based on data in the WP user object. For example:

If a user that is not logged in clicks the button they are directed to my login page.

If a user that is logged in clicks the button I want them to be dynamically re-directed to the right page to book - This will be based on data from a required field from the registration form.

First question: In what ways can I achieve this? I assume that I would use a PHP script? If so, I am familiar with using custom php and adding it in like a plugin. But I am not sure how I would link this to a button click. The button in particular is formatted via the Astra Theme editor and I can only see an option to add an HTML link. Can I link direct to a php script?

Second question: What would the code look like to retrieve the data from the WP user object?

Third question: Once I have the data - Would I use a php switch to handle the re-direct - Like so:

```
   case 'London':
$redirect_to = 'http://example.com/my-page/london';
break;

case 'New York':
$redirect_to = 'http://example.com/my-page/new-york/';
break;

default:
$redirect_to = 'http://example.com/my-page/some-default-page';
break;

}

// the "if" check here is just in case $redirect_to is accidentally empty
if ( isset( $redirect_to ) ) {
wp_redirect( $redirect_to );
exit();
}
}
```

Many thanks,

Guy

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<?php
if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $city = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'city', true ); // Get the prevered city from the user meta.

    // Detirmine the redirect url for the selected city
    switch ($city) {
        case 'london':
            $redirect_to = '/cities/london';
            break;
        case 'amsterdam':
            $redirect_to = '/cities/amsterdam';
            break;
        default:
            $redirect_to = '/cities'; // if no city provided.
    }

    // make a link to the selecte url.
    echo '<button onclick="window.location.href=\'' . $redirect_to . '\'">' . $city . '</button>';

} else {
    wp_redirect('/login'); // If user is not loged in, redirect to the login page.
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks - Do you know how I run this script upon button click?

Comment: You can echo the correct link on a A tag or on a button with onclick="window.location.href='/<?php echo $redirect_to; ?>'"

Comment: Thanks - I assume the $redirect_to will be where the php script saves the correct value? What does echo do? Just return that value? So the link will go to www.example.com/$redirect_to ?

Comment: Yes! <a href="http://www.example.com/<?php echo $redirect_to; ?>">Link tekst</a>

Comment: Sorry to ask about this again - I am unsure about a couple of things. The code that you provided initially seems to set up $city then in the link code below in the comments - onclick="window.location.href='/<?php echo $redirect_to; ?>'" we are referencing $redirect_to 

Are these just examples? I am finding it hard to understand how this links together.

Comment: I have updated my answer to include your switch logic. I hope it makes more sense now?

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me! I copied the code above into my custom function. Sadly after that I I have a critical error on when I open my website. Do I need to put anything else before the If to define it as a function?

Comment: Also is this meant to be in the middle of the code:  // make a link to the selecte url.
    echo '<a href="' . $redirect_to . '">All things in ' . $city . '</a>'; or should I remove this part from the function and use this as the button link?

Comment: Also is the code for the link: echo '<a href="' . $redirect_to . '">All things in ' . $city . '</a>'; can I remove the 'All things in' section as the button has text that I define in my theme builder or does this serve another purpose?

Comment: I have fixed the fatal error by adding "function user_redirect() {" before the If statement. I had added the echo '<a href="' . $redirect_to . '">All things in ' . $city . '</a>' code to my button. When clicked it takes me to the following URL which is incorrect: https://example.com/echo%20%3Ca%20href=%22%20.%20redirect_to%20.%20%22%3EAll%20things%20in%20%20.%20city%20.%20%3C/a%3E

Comment: Also I have no idea if I should have added the "function user_redirect() {" just everything else in my custom function had this or add_action before going into the code...?

Comment: @GuyBeardsley There was a error in the code indeed, i changed the example above! But the example asumes you have a user meta field called city? If not, where are you getting the city from? Also you can put this code inside your template file where you want the link/button to be.

Comment: I changed the city to 'Location' which is the name of the meta field I am using. What do you mean by the template file? I am using a theme builder so have put things like this in my_custom_plugin plugin. Will that work in this instance? So the button link is :     echo '<button onclick="window.location.href=\'' . $redirect_to . '\'">' . $city . '</button>';
?

Comment: I set the button link as above (not sure if that is correct) and put the code in my custom plugin. When the button is clicked it takes me to the following URL https://example.com/echo%20%3Cbutton%20onclick=%22window.location.href=/%20.%20redirect_to%20.%20/%22%3E%20.%20city%20.%20%3C/button%3E

Comment: change your code to be <?php echo '<button onclick="window.location.href=\'' . $redirect_to . '\'">' . $city . '</button>'; ?>  It needs the <?php and ?> around it else php will not be interpreted.

Comment: And dont put this code inside a link or a button the code will create the entire button. And also don't put the example.com in front of it. If it still doesn't work, post your code you have so far.